# New VLAN Cisco Switch SF300

Tags: networking

I've been having some trouble configuring a new set of vlans on my SF300, both in the terminal and web GUI. I have tried both, also this is my first time configuring a switch. Here is what I have done so far:

#Created vlan 2 with access ports 1-3 assigned for host usage.

#Created vlan 3 with access ports 22-24 assigned for servers.

[image]

I want the vlans not capable of communicating with one another. According to my understanding, access ports are used for hosts and trunk ports are used for switch to switch connection when trunking vlans, or switch to router. This is why I have port 12 as trunk, since it is my router connection. My problem is not having any internet on my vlans, no matter what I do. I tried adding the vlan 2 and 3 to the vlan 1 membership on port 12. I'm looking for a better understanding on how to give internet connection to my vlans.

Thanks!